# Polyglossia and Makeidx

Tags: polyglossia, makeindex

I am trying to index Arabic documents. The idx file generated is:

```
\indexentry{الوعي|hyperpage}{\RLE {١}}
\indexentry{المسؤولية|hyperpage}{\RLE {٢}}
```

When I run makeindex, I get this error in ilg file

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2019] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file Coaching.idx...
!! Input index error (file = Coaching.idx, line = 1):
    -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.
!! Input index error (file = Coaching.idx, line = 2):
    -- Illegal space within numerals in second argument.
done (0 entries accepted, 2 rejected).
Nothing written in Coaching.ind.
Transcript written in Coaching.ilg.
```

How can I fix this? Is there a work-around to have an index generated?
Thx

Comment: You should use `xindy` rather than `makeindex` for this task.

Comment: I tried it but I guess I didn't do it right. Let me revisit and revert back.

Comment: I tried once more. I am afraid xindy does not support Arabic. How can I create one?

Comment: The problem is in {\RLE {١}}. Note the number is Arabic. If I remove {\RLE {١}} with {1}, things works fine. How to prevent makeidx from adding \RLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have added the following:

```
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
```

and the idx outupt file is now:

```
\indexentry{الوعي|hyperpage}{1}
\indexentry{المسؤولية|hyperpage}{2}
```